# On go daddy paypal is not getting any response

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

Hello I implemented paypal express checkout API in PHP, On my localhost it successfully running but on Go daddy hosting server it will not displaying anything, It only display one blank page, It dont even go on paypal page nor it will displaying any error message. I guess may be curl request or https response is the problem

Here is my curl request.

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
        $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

        // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        // Get response from the server.
        $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

        if(!$httpResponse) {
            exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
        }

        // Extract the response details.
        $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

        $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
        foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
            $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
            if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
                $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
            }
        }

        if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
            exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
        }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
```

For more reference this is the code i [integrated](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php).

I am sure there is some problem in either curl request or https response please guide me as soon as possible.

Comment: For future reference you may want to take a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It makes any API call you want to make with PayPal very quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your script.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

That will allow you to see the PHP error that is happening.

You may also want to change this...

```
if(!$httpResponse) {
            exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
        }
```

to...

```
    if($curl_error($ch)) { 
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
}
```

The way you have it, if anything at all gets brought back to $httpResponse it would be treated as true.  Checking for a curl error there, though, will always output the error message and number if an error with curl does occur.

Comment: Hi Andrew thank you, but still same problem nothing is happening. From Localhost it is working, I guess something missing for go daddy server.

Comment: A blank PHP page generally means there's a PHP error happening but errors are not being displayed.  That first snippet I gave you should override that.  If it's not you must have something else like htaccess or php.ini disabling errors for good somehow.  In any case, you should be able to see the PHP errors if you look at your raw web server logs.

Comment: hey thank you very much, it worked, sorry for late reply